# If $f$ is a modular form and $y^{k/2}f$ stays bounded as $y\rightarrow \infty$, its constant Fourier coefficients at the cusps are zero

Tags: complex-analysis, modular-forms

Let $f(\tau)$ be a modular form of weight $k$, where $\tau = x + iy \in \mathbb H$. Then $f$ is a cusp form if its constant Fourier coefficients at the cusps are zero. By modularity, it suffices to check at one cusp, say infinity.

Why does the constant Fourier coefficient at $\infty$ vanish if $y^{k/2}f$ stays bounded as $y\rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: I rolled back your question to the original version. If you have another question or if one of the answers is not clear, you can either comment under the answer or ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You mean $f$ is weight $k$-modular for the full modular group. $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}) \setminus\mathbb{H}$ has only one cusp : $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}) i\infty = \mathbb{Q} \cup i\infty$.

That $f$ is analytic on $\mathbb{H}$ and $f(z) = f(z+1)$ implies $$F(q) = f(\frac{\log q}{2i\pi})$$ is analytic for $0 < |q| < 1$ so it has a Laurent expansion valid for $0 < |q|< 1$ 
$$F(q) = \sum_n a_n q^n, \qquad f(z) = \sum_n^\infty a_n e^{2i \pi nz}$$

Then there are $4$ cases for the behavior at $q=0$

- $F$ has an essential singularity, $F(q) q^k$ is not bounded for any $k$
- $F$ has a pole, $F(q) q^m$ is analytic ($f$ is a meromorphic modular form)
- $F$ is analytic, $a_n=0$ for $n<0$ ($f$ is a modular form)
- $F(0) = 0$ so $F(q) = a_m q^m +O(q^{m+1})$ for some $m \ge 1$ ($f$ is a cusp form)

For any $z$
$$a_n e^{2i \pi nz}= \int_0^1 f(z+x) e^{-2i \pi nx}dx$$
from $f(z) = z^k f(-1/z)$, if $f$ is a cusp form, taking $z= i/n$ we have a bound $a_n= O(n^{k/2})$.

Comment: $f(i/n) = (i/n)^k f(ni)$, and the two factors on the RHS go to zero as $n\rightarrow \infty$. How does this imply that $a_n = O(n^{k/2})$ and how does this bound give that $y^{k/2}f<C$ as $y\rightarrow\infty$?

Comment: Second last line, isn't it $f(z) = z^{-k}f(-1/z)$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $F(q) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nq^n$ be the Fourier expansion of $f$ at infinity.  So $F(q)$ is holomorphic in the disc $|q| < 1$, and we have $f(z) = F(e^{2\pi i z})$ for all $z \in \mathbb H$.  Suppose that for all $x$, $f(x+iy)y^{k/2}$ is bounded as $y$ goes to infinity.  You want to show that the constant term $a_0$ is zero.

The only way $f(iy)y^{k/2}$ could be bounded as $y \to \infty$ is if $f(iy) = F(e^{-2\pi y})$ is going to zero.

But $$\lim\limits_{y \to \infty} F(e^{-2\pi y}) = F(0) = a_0$$